# calling of javascript function on button click in .module file in drupal

Tags: drupal-6

I have one button and onclick i want javascript function to be called which contains alert message...............in drupal

i tried many things like...........
1)i created button using
         $form['click'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#attributes' => array('onclick' =>_____________),//dnt know what to give for onclick
    '#value' => t('click'),
  );

2)used drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'document').'/eg.js', 'module');in hook_form_alter()

3).js file is as follows
       function message()
        {
            alert("Catch ->This alert box was called");
        } -->

want alert message to be displayed on button click.
Kindly help................
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
$form['search_something'] = array(
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#value' => t('Search'),
      '#attributes' => array('onclick' => 'searchsomething()),
  );
```

this is the piece of code to call javascript on button click.

Javascript function

```
function searchsomething(){
  alert("hello");
}
```